# Simple deform modifier is deforming my object

Tags: modifiers

Im using the array modifier and simple deform modifier to make an array of circles, but the middle section object is deformed, and the outer circle shapes are not squashed. I'd like the circles to be non squashed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a grid object, array it, use simple deform (as you probably did for the array of spheres).

Then parent the sphere to the grid, and in the grid instancing part, use "vertices" and disable "show instancer":

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

*Simple Deform* will deform, but you could use a first *Array* on Y:

[image]

Then create an empty at the same location as your original object, give your object a second *Array* with the *Object Offset* option, select the empty as *Object Offset*, move it on X, rotate it, move it on Y until it gives you the desired result:

[image]

Comment: What can I say, both methods are amazing, always learning something in this forum. They're both good methods.